# How to split a list which contains sentences into a list with words using Python?

Tags: python, arrays, list, split

I have a list with sentences in Python:

```
list1 = ["This is the first sentence", "This is the second", "This is the third"]
```

I tried using split(" "):

```
sth = []
for i in list1:
    sth.append(i.split(" "))
```

But this way I get a 2D array, which contains regular lists from the sentences with their words, so something like this:

```
[["This", "is", "the", "first", "sentence"], ["This", "is", "the", "second"], ["This", "is", "the", "third"]]
```

I would like the outcome to be a regular list, this way:

```
["This", "is", "the", "first", "sentence", "This", "is", "the", "second", "This", "is", "the", "third"]
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Use `sth.extend(...)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to use `extend` instead of `append`.

The basic difference between **append** and **extend** is that **append** is used to add **one** element at the end of the existing list while **extend** is used when we have to merge two list extend will **iterate** through the passed argument and add them to the existing list at a index of n+1,n+2,n+3…(where n is existing length of the list)

Here is the code:

```py
list1 = ["This is the first sentence", "This is the second", "This is the third"]

sth = []
for i in list1:
    sth.extend(i.split(" "))   # Here is the change
```

Here is the output from terminal:

```
>>> print(sth)
['This', 'is', 'the', 'first', 'sentence', 'This', 'is', 'the', 'second', 'This', 'is', 'the', 'third']
```

Answer (score 4):

try using `extend` instead of `append`.
full code:

```
list1 = ["This is the first sentence", "This is the second", "This is the third"]
sth = []
for i in list1:
    sth.extend(i.split(" "))
```

Output:

```
['This', 'is', 'the', 'first', 'sentence', 'This', 'is', 'the', 'second', 'This', 'is', 'the', 'third']
```

Answer (score 4):

This should do it:

```
' '.join(l).split()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sth = []
for i in list1:
    sth += i.split(" ")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [chain](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain)

```
from itertools import chain
list(chain(*[["This", "is", "the", "first", "sentence"], ["This", "is", "the", "second"], ["This", "is", "the", "third"]]))
```

Answer (score 1):

With list comprehension its a single line of code

```
list1 = [["This", "is", "the", "first", "sentence"], ["This", "is", "the", "second"], ["This", "is", "the", "third"]]

print( [item for subl in list1 for item in subl] )
OUT: ['This', 'is', 'the', 'first', 'sentence', 'This', 'is', 'the', 'second', 'This', 'is', 'the', 'third']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
list1 = ["This is the first sentence", "This is the second", "This is the third"]
l1 = []
for i in list1:
    l2 = i.split()
    for j in range(len(l2)):
        l1.append(l2[j])
print(l1)
```

output:

```
['This', 'is', 'the', 'first', 'sentence', 'This', 'is', 'the', 'second', 'This', 'is', 'the', 'third']
```

Comment: This is not the correct input set (his input consists of nested lists), it does not work with the correct input the OP provided.